# Keycloak behind apache reverse proxy

Tags: reverse-proxy, keycloak

I have surfed through google without finding any **concrete** answers or **examples**, so again trying my luck here (often get lucky).

**The problem**

- I have a single spring boot RESTful service running behind an apache
  reverse proxy. This RESTful service is running HTTP only. Say it's running on
  local ip 172.s port 8080.
- I have also configured an apache reverse proxy. Say it's running on
  local ip 172.a and public ip 55.a. This proxy responds to both port 80, but all the HTTP traffic is automatically redirected to 443.
- I have another server running a standalone Keycloak server. Also
  this server is configured to be public accessible through the
  reverse proxy. Say it's running on local ip 172.k. This Keycloak server is running on HTTP-only. The HTTP requests are handled using SSL over the reverse proxy.
- Last, I have another frontend-webapp running on local ip 172.f. This frontend-webapp is running under Nodejs, and is also configured through the reverse proxy. It's also running only HTTP, but client(browser) is using SSL through the reverse proxy, just as for the Keycloak and RESTful service. This frontend is consuming the RESTful service, and is also configured to authenticate using the keycloak javascript adapter.
- The RESTful service is configured as bearer-only using Spring Boot Keycloak adapter, while the frontend app is configured with access type public.

The RESTful service server, Keycloak server, and the frontend server are not public accessible; they are accessible only through the reverse proxy. But they can communicate with each other (since they are in the same private network).

In the frontend keycloak.json file, the `auth-server-url` is set to the proxy url `https://example.com/auth`, and the frontend is able to successfully get a valid token. Now when I try to consume the RESTful service, I get a error in RESTful adapter that the token issuer is invalid. In the http-header I am, of course, sending the `Authorization: Bearer <token>`. The reason I am getting this error is that in RESTful keycloak configuation, I have configured the `auth-server-url` to use the local url `http://172.k:9080/auth`, so this url is different from the one in the token (which is `https://example.com/auth`).

**Question**

I cannot include the same `auth-server-url` in the RESTful service as for the frontend, because that will require me to also setup HTTPs on the RESTful service (because that url is https), and that will complicate stuff a lot, including the need to setup certificates and stuff like that. Also I think it's inefficient and not practical to setup SSL on local only servers.

So my question is how I can make the adapter talk to the Keycloak without going through the reverse proxy. I want the RESTful adapter to talk to the Keyclok server for token verification through `auth-server-url: http://172.k:9080/auth`.

Earlier there was a different url for backend, that got removed: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-2623

Comment: Have you try to set Web Origins to *. If I'm right I got the same problem by cross domain access

Comment: Yes I have tried setting Web-origins to '*' without any success.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50670734/keycloak-in-docker-compose-network

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried different things, but could not solve the problem. To me it seems like there is not way to specify `auth-server-url: http://172.k:9080/auth` in the backend adapter while the frontend adapter is putting `auth-server-url:https://example.com/auth` in the token. So my solution was to configure all the backend services to also the `auth-server-url: https://example.com/auth`.

The only disadvantage of this is that my backend service adapter communicates with keycloak over web, which probably is not so good performance wise, but at least everything works as it should. It should have been possible to somehow specify a local keycloak endpoint within the same local network, or the same VPN in AWS.

Comment: To the reader: if you have alternative solutions, please do provide an answer, I will gladly accept our answer.

Comment: This is so sad :( Data or bandwidth are expensive, thus going through public net is a big waste...

Comment: I'm struggling with this as well. I'm trying to migrate my keycloak-server to a new URL while the backend is at the same URL. All my mobile phone apps out in the wild will take some time to update and start using the new URL. So in the meantime, I need to accept both URLs in my backend adapter.

Answer (score 6):

You need to inform keycloak about the location of the reverse proxy. Then in its response it will set location to there instead of its local address. To do that in the latest keycloak set the environment variable `KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL` to point to
the string `https://example.com/auth` (yes, it needs the whole address.
To make this work, also set `PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING` to the value `true`

If it's a Docker container, that means:

```
environment:
  ...
  PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING: "true"
  KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL: "https://example.com/auth"
```

Alternately, you can set `KEYCLOAK_HOSTNAME` to `example.com` and that will leave the port number, for which???(not sure how to do this part yet, if you find out please let me know... ) )

EDIT: Note that in some cases, you might want to set this only for a specific client. While configuring each client from inside keycloak, you can set its Frontend_URL from the first options tab.

Comment: Thank you. I put       - KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL=http://keycloak:8080/auth into my docker-compose.yml, and it works like a charm! The openid endpoint configuration looks usable now.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using Keycloak for a project in docker containers. I had the same problem but in a local network (so maybe this will not be the solution, in this case i'm sorry). So this was the situation:

- REST java webapp running on wildfly, in a single Docker container
- Keycloak running in a single Docker container in the same network of the previous
- Apache running locally on my machine outside Docker, serving an angular 2 app, with the properly config
- The angular 2 app's adapter was pointing the url http://aaa.auth.com (i modified the local file hosts with the entry 127.0.0.1 aaa.auth.com)
- I added a link between Wildfly Docker and Keycloak Docker by the hostname http://aaa.auth.com and i used this hostname in the Java webapp adapter.
- Both the adapters were pointing to the same address, as far as i know this is a Keycloak requirement, see https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-2067

There are a lot of differences from your case (Docker, HTTP vs HTTPS etc), but, to avoid the communication REST-Keycloak via Web, have you tried modifying the file hosts of your server (hosting the RESTful service) inserting an entry with the local IP of your reverse proxy (172.a) and "example.com"?

Or, maybe you can solve it with a private DNS?

Answer (score 2):

I've had a similar problem in a docker swarm environment. My Keycloak and my spring boot container were both behind the same reverse proxy.

**For Tomcat:**
The matter is to configure the http(s) connector correctly. Let's say the host name and port of our reverse proxy are http://${EXTERNAL_HOSTNAME}:${EXTERNAL_PORT}.

Then the http(s) connector in tomcat.xml should have those two additional attributes:

```
<Connector [...] proxyName="${EXTERNAL_HOSTNAME}" proxyPort="${EXTERNAL_PORT}"/>
```

This will make all calls to servletRequest.getServerName() and servletRequest.getServerPort() respond with the values of our reverse proxy. The keycloak adapter certainly uses these functions to determine the redirect url.

For Spring Boot: Drop this class in your classpath:

```
@Component
public class TomcatReverseProxyCustomizer implements WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatServletWebServerFactory>, TomcatConnectorCustomizer {

    @Value("${server.tomcat.proxy-name}")
    private String proxyName;
    @Value("${server.tomcat.proxy-port}")
    private int proxyPort;

    @Override
    public void customize(final TomcatServletWebServerFactory factory) {
        factory.addConnectorCustomizers(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void customize(final Connector connector) {
        connector.setProxyName(this.proxyName);
        connector.setProxyPort(this.proxyPort);
    }

}
```

and then setting this in application.properties:

```
server.tomcat.proxy-name=${EXTERNAL_HOSTNAME}
server.tomcat.proxy-port=${EXTERNAL_PORT}
```

**Additional Configuration of the keycloak adapter (Examples are for Spring Boot):**

My keycloak is also behind the same reverse proxy. So I also had to set the auth server url of the keycloak adapter to the hostname of the reverse proxy. Then I abused the proxy setting of the keycloak adapter to make it use the services on the internal leg:

```
keycloak.auth-server-url=http://${EXTERNAL_HOSTNAME}:${EXTERNAL_PORT}/auth
keycloak.proxy-url=http://${INTERNAL_KEYCLOAK_HOSTNAME}:${INTERNAL_KEYCLOAK_PORT}/auth
```

Also these settings might make some sense:

```
server.servlet.session.cookie.domain=${EXTERNAL_HOSTNAME}
server.use-forward-headers=true
server.tomcat.remote-ip-header=x-forwarded-for
server.tomcat.protocol-header=x-forwarded-proto
```

server.tomcat.protocol-header is important for those who terminate SSL on their reverse proxy.

Answer (score 2):

One of the solutions is to upgrade the adapter to 8.0.0. This problem seems to be fixed in version 8.0.0.

It was known problem [KEYCLOAK-6073](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-6073):

> Add support for OpenID Connect Discovery to Java adapters...
> Adapters should support using different URLs for frontend and backend requests.

Comment: Hi could you please provide a sample? I am confused how to make use of the new feature. Thanks!