# JHipster keycloak docker configuration for production

Tags: jhipster, keycloak

My JHipster(v4.11.1) project is using Monolithic architecture with OAuth 2.0 authentication type. I did face couple of issue for hosting it in a production server. Currently here are not fixed yet ones:

After I do click 'Sign in' link I get redirect into following url:

https://*my-domain-name*/auth/realms/jhipster/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=web_app&redirect_uri=http://**my-docker-service-name**/login&response_type=code&scope=openid%20profile%20email&state=hO2NCQ

First issue is, here I need **my-docker-service-name** to be *my-domain-name* (and using https).

Note: Here I do see keycloak login page with following error message: `Invalid parameter: redirect_uri`

If I do change `redirect_uri` into my domain name manually, then I see keycloak login page without error. Next issue is after I do enter username/password, I get redirect into following url:

http://**keycloak**/auth/realms/jhipster/login-actions/authenticate?code=3MADiKg19-SL1L_lOmMEJv4w3kmGlF--0hyIDInKPm8&execution=07cacbc6-5b72-407e-9a0c-9a1b6447a7ff&client_id=web_app

And as you can see my second issue is **keycloak** need to be *my-domain-name* (and using https).

Note: Here if change the url manually into my-domain-name, then I see login page with invalid username/password error message.

Moreover I do have same problem for accessing keycloak administration console(it get redirect into http://**keycloak**) and I can't see the login page(`Invalid parameter: redirect_uri`).

I can provide more information regards to my production configurations if needed? for instance I do use Nginx as reverse proxy and also for handling https requests. My Nginx instance is a docker container and using default docker network for finding it's upstreams (keycloak(for `/auth` path) and my-app(for `/` path).

Even I did face above issues, so far I am very happy with the result and I would like to Thank you JHipster team, Keycloak team and Matt Raible! :-) for making it possible for us to use this great frameworks together! Cheers!

Comment: I found following question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42342367/2179502 quite similar to this question, and provided workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42504805/2179502 as a way to progress forward. But as author of this solution mentioned the disadvantage is every request must goes through web for finding Keycloak instance! and we cann't benefit from our local network for communicating with Keycloak instance.

Answer (score 1):

First of all [this section(8.3. Setting Up a Load Balancer or Proxy)](http://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/index.html#_setting-up-a-load-balancer-or-proxy) of Keycloak documentation was absolutely helpful. I was able to make things somehow working but I still feel things can get done better and in more secure way!

I am not going to repeat needed configuration for Keycloak side, but I rather provide some hints for you in case you are using Nginx as reverse proxy.

Here is my `nginx.conf` which includes required configs:

```

```
upstream rock-app {
    server rock-app:8080;
}
upstream keycloak {
    server keycloak:9080;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    ...
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=86400; includeSubdomains; preload" always;
    ...
}

location / {
    proxy_set_header HOST $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass http://rock-app;
}

location /auth {
    proxy_set_header HOST $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass http://keycloak;
}
```

```

Note: `add_header Strict-Transport-Security ...` part is important and ensure us users will stay in https protocol when they enter the site with a https url. please correct me if I am wrong!?

Now If I visit following url:

`https://my-example.com/auth/realms/jhipster/.well-known/openid-configuration`

I will see this response:

```
{
    "issuer": "http://my-example.com/auth/realms/jhipster",
    "authorization_endpoint": "http://my-example.com/auth/realms/jhipster/protocol/openid-connect/auth",
    "token_endpoint": "http://my-example.com/auth/realms/jhipster/protocol/openid-connect/token",
    "token_introspection_endpoint": "http://my-example.com/auth/realms/jhipster/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect",
    "userinfo_endpoint": "http://my-example.com/auth/realms/jhipster/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo",
    "end_session_endpoint": "http://my-example.com/auth/realms/jhipster/protocol/openid-connect/logout",
    "jwks_uri": "http://my-example.com/auth/realms/jhipster/protocol/openid-connect/certs",
    "check_session_iframe": "http://my-example.com/auth/realms/jhipster/protocol/openid-connect/login-status-iframe.html",
    "grant_types_supported": ["authorization_code", "implicit", "refresh_token", "password", "client_credentials"],
    "response_types_supported": ["code", "none", "id_token", "token", "id_token token", "code id_token", "code token", "code id_token token"],
    "subject_types_supported": ["public", "pairwise"],
    "id_token_signing_alg_values_supported": ["RS256"],
    "userinfo_signing_alg_values_supported": ["RS256"],
    "request_object_signing_alg_values_supported": ["none", "RS256"],
    "response_modes_supported": ["query", "fragment", "form_post"],
    "registration_endpoint": "http://my-example.com/auth/realms/jhipster/clients-registrations/openid-connect",
    "token_endpoint_auth_methods_supported": ["private_key_jwt", "client_secret_basic", "client_secret_post"],
    "token_endpoint_auth_signing_alg_values_supported": ["RS256"],
    "claims_supported": ["sub", "iss", "auth_time", "name", "given_name", "family_name", "preferred_username", "email"],
    "claim_types_supported": ["normal"],
    "claims_parameter_supported": false,
    "scopes_supported": ["openid", "offline_access"],
    "request_parameter_supported": true,
    "request_uri_parameter_supported": true
}
```

As you may notice `http://my-example.com/...` is shown instead of `https://my-example.com/...`

Therefore I had to change following config of my realm(jhipster-realm.json) from
`"sslRequired" : "external",`
to 
`"sslRequired" : "none",` which I don't know if is a bad thing? considering (1) my browser never leaves https when I do test login workflow and (2) my keycloak instance is **not** accessible through any public port.

Well I am not going to accept my own answer as accepted answer, because as I said earlier I feel things can get done better and in more secure way. Thanks!

**Update**

I've done following changes for using https protocol:

*Dockerfile*

```
FROM jboss/keycloak:3.4.1.Final
```

*standalone.xml*

```
<server name="default-server">
    ...
    <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="proxy-https" proxy-address-forwarding="${env.PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING}" certificate-forwarding="true" enable-http2="true"/>
    <https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" security-realm="ApplicationRealm" proxy-address-forwarding="${env.PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING}" certificate-forwarding="true" enable-http2="true"/>
...

<socket-binding-group ...
    <socket-binding name="proxy-https" port="443"/>
...
```

*nginx.conf*

```
upstream keycloak {
    server keycloak:9443;
}
...
server {
    listen 80;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    ...
    location /auth {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass https://keycloak;
    }
...
```

*jhipster-realm.json*

```
...
"sslRequired": "external",
```

HTH, Thanks!