# Keycloak InvalidBearerTokenException Invalid issuer

Tags: java, spring, keycloak

I have a Java Spring backend running in a docker container and then a Keycloak also running in a separate container. Both on their own networks.

When I try to make a request to the Java backend that is protected by the keycloak BE with OAUTH, I get this error:

```
InvalidBearerTokenException: Invalid issuer
```

I am setting the location of the keycloak server in the java be as the IP of the gateway of the container. From what I understand because this gateway IP is not the same as the issuer url that is why it gives this error.

I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61966384/keycloak-invalid-token-issuer) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42342367/keycloak-behind-apache-reverse-proxy/42504805#42504805) questions and tried to implement some of the solutions to no avail. Maybe I am not understanding them..

I have tried to set KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL on the admin dashboard to the ip of the api gateway but this then does not let me get the access token in postman has it will redirect to this ip, and break the auth flow.

I have also tried setting this:

```
  PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING: "true"
  KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL: "https://example.com/auth"
```

No luck.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong and point me in the right direction ? Please tell me if you need more information.

This is what my security filter looks like on the backend:

```
    @Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable().authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> {
                try {
                    authorize
                            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/development/deleteAllUsers").permitAll()
                            .mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/createUser").permitAll()
                            .mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/test").permitAll()
                            .anyRequest().authenticated();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            })
            .oauth2ResourceServer(
                    oauth2 -> oauth2.authenticationManagerResolver(getJwtIssuerAuthenticationManagerResolver()));

    http.headers()
            .xssProtection()
            .disable()
            .frameOptions()
            .deny()
            .contentSecurityPolicy("default-src 'self'");

    return http.build();
}

@Bean("CurrentUser")
public Supplier<JwtAuthenticationToken> currentUser() {
    return () -> (JwtAuthenticationToken) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
}

private JwtIssuerAuthenticationManagerResolver getJwtIssuerAuthenticationManagerResolver() {
    Map<String, AuthenticationManager> managers = providersProperty.getProviders()
            .values()
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(p -> p.getIssuerUri(),
                    p -> jwtProviderStrategy.getProvider(p.getKey())::authenticate));

    return new JwtIssuerAuthenticationManagerResolver(managers::get);
}
```

Also I am setting this properties in application.yml

```
 jwk-set-uri: http://${KEYCLOAK_HOST:localhost}:${KEYCLOAK_PORT:8180}/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/certs
 issuer-uri: http://${KEYCLOAK_HOST:localhost}:${KEYCLOAK_PORT:8180}/auth/realms/myrealm
```

If I run the Java backend locally it work normally. Just breaks on docker.

Comment: There really isn't enough information here to answer properly but normally you validate the `iss` field in a JWT with a previously known issuer.  Keycloak, by default, has an issuer that looks like `https://hostname/realms/realmName`.  Do you know how you are validating the token?  Is this using something like Quarkus or Spring or something else?

Comment: Yeah sorry. Its just ussing spring.

Comment: Do you have the "well known" URL setup correctly?  Check the docs [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html) for the issuer information.

Comment: @stdunbar I updated the question with my jwk-set-uri var that I am using.

Comment: What version of Keycloak are you using?  The URL with "/auth" in it was removed in Keycloak 18.  It's the same URL but without the "/auth" part.

Comment: I dont believe it should be that...
I am running this image: jboss/keycloak:15.0.2

This run ok locally. With the keycloak in a container and the be running locally it all works. Just when the be is in a container it breaks..

Comment: @stdunbar I  have found a solution but it feels super hacky. Care to give your opinion?

Answer (score 0):

Just add a mapping to your hosts file in windows is:
*C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts*

It should be like so:

```
127.0.0.1 keycloakblog
```

keycloakblog being your container name.

Then when creating your oauth request just use this host name for it.

```
http://keycloakblog:8080/auth/realms/wheelmeet/protocol/openid-connect/auth
```

If you use localhost, witch you still can because they are the same, keycloak will set the issuer as localhost, but if you use the name of the host you just maped the issuer will be that name.

After that just set the Java issuer/jwt strings to the host name you chose. If you run the Java server in a container it will try to go to *keycloakblog* and that will resolve it as the container name. If you run the Java server outside the container it will try to go to *keycloakblog* and resolve it as localhost. Both will work.

**OLD SOLUTION:**

***Atention!** If for any reason you do use this solution keep in mind that on spring 3+ the jwt decoder is nimbus-jose and it does not decode the jwt if it has 2 claims with the same name. Previous Spring versions work fine.*

Ok so I found a solution. But it seems super hacky and doesn't feel at all like the right way to get it done.

So like I said the problem was that the **issuer is not the same as the one on the access token**. If the keycloak server would be on the web it would be no problem because the url would be the same, but because the keycloak server is running in a container I have to either give Java the gateway IP or the container name (if its on the same network). But then the issuer will not be the same and throw said error.

The solution is simple enough. Just create a mapper for the "iss" claim in the access token and put in either the gateway ip or the container name. I switched  everything back to only one network (this was how it was first) and just putted the container name. Like so:
[image]

Does anybody know if there are any security concerns doing this?
Also would this be suitable for a production enviroment?

Please respond with a better solution if you have one!

Answer (score 0):

What you want is probably setting [Keycloak `hostname` configuration properties](https://www.keycloak.org/server/hostname) with DNS entry that is reachable by all actors: OAuth2 client, OAuth2 resource server and user browser. If you don't have one yet, then maybe you should [configure docker](https://docs.docker.com/network/) for that.

Also you don't have to configure Spring Boot `issuer-uri` if you provide a `jwk-set-uri`: only the JWKS endpoint is required to fetch the public key used to validate tokens. Issuer URI serves two purposes:

- adds an issuer validator to JWT decoders (if not provided, the `iss` claim is not checked, which would remove your error)
- if the JWKS endpoint is not explicitly configured, give the opportunity to find the OpenID configuration by trying a few "well-known" paths, and get the JWKS endpoint from this conf.

So if your Keycloak conf is OK, only one of `jwk-set-uri` and `issuer-uri` is required (you have to provide the two only when the host in `iss` claim is not reachable by clients and resource servers **and** you want `iss` claim validator in JWT decoder).

`issuer-uri` is generally preferred because it adds the check on `iss` claim (but you already know that the token was signed with the right private key, so ...)

Comment: If I do that It wont properly complete the authorization flow.

Comment: Why that? you set as hostname a DNS entry that is reachable by all actors: OAuth2 client, OAuth2 resource server and user browser

Comment: I'm so lost... I dont understand what should I do with DNS... Do I have to configure a local DNS server? Or just some setting in docker ?  Like the "--hostname" ?

Comment: You use the **same name** for your authorization server in it's conf (`hostanme` in keycloak configuration), in docker (`--hostname`), in Spring Security configuration properties, and in client conf if using a "public" client. What is complicated there?

Comment: If I change the hostname in keycloak to the docker container hostname (and put the hostname mapping in the hosts file in windows) I cant even complete the oauth flow for login. Just get 400 Bad request...

Comment: I suggest that you follow [this very simple tutorial](https://github.com/tvogel8570/samples/tree/main/infrastructure/keycloak). It works for me like a charm using `https://bravo-ch4mp:8443/realms/master`, `bravo-ch4mp` being my laptop hostname. I set that as value for `container_name` in the `compose.yaml` the author of this tutorial kindly provides.

Comment: Got it to work with just creating a host mapping in windows to the name of the keycloak container in docker... Feel like I tried that before, but I guess I was doing something wrong.... Thanks for the input! <3

Comment: Well, that has to do with the "reachable by all actors" in the 1st paragraph. Using your hostname is simpler, configuring a DNS server on your network more complicated, but the 3 should work.